# HTML5 Image.onload race condition in Internet Explorer 9

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-9, html5-canvas

I've found similar timing issues concerning IE 9 and drawing images to HTML5 cnavases discussed on stackoverflow, but none quite match mine.

I'm encountering an issue such that periodically the image's onload function is called, but it is still not ready to be drawn to a canvas.  (The canvas remains blank).  Within onload, the image's "complete" property is always true, and the "width" and "height" properties always contain the expected values.  No exceptions are thrown.  If I put a small delay in onload prior to drawing the image to the canvas, I never get a blank draw.  I can also tie another attempt to draw the image to an event like a mouse click, and this is always successful.  I do not observe this in Chrome or Firefox.  I appreciate any insights.  Thanks!

```
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
canvas.width = 640;
canvas.height = 480;

var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

var image = new Image();

image.onload = function()
{   
    // this.complete always true here
    // A delay here seems to guarantee the draw will succeed
    context.drawImage(this, 0, 0);  // Half the time canvas remains blank after draw
    // If the canvas is still blank, a later call to context.drawImage with this image will succeed

}

image.src = "some.png";
```

Comment: I should add that even more frustrating is that if I have the IE 9 debugger open (with F12), this timing issue never occurs.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see where you append the canvas to the body--is that intentional?

Anyway, try putting the `createElement` inside the `onload`

Does this make things consistently good?

```
    var canvas;
    var context;

    var image = new Image();

    image.onload = function()
    { 
        canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
        canvas.width = 640;
        canvas.height = 480;
        document.body.appendChild(canvas);
        context = canvas.getContext("2d");

        context.drawImage(this, 0, 0);  // Half the time canvas remains blank after draw
    }
    image.src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/stackoverflow/city-q-c-640-480-6.jpg";
```

Comment: Thank you for your response.  You are correct that I am not appending the canvas to the body of the document in my example.  I copy it repeatedly to an actual document canvas in a setInterval loop once the image is marked as loaded.  (It's the background for a game).  Creating the element in the onload as you suggested made the issue less frequent, but did not prevent it entirely.  However, I believe this is because this delayed the time between onload being called and drawImage being executed.  I could achieve the same improvement by placing an empty for loop immediately prior to drawing too.

Comment: **You shouldn't need any delaying loops at all.**  At this point all the code inside the onload is being executed synchronously.  Any other clues?  BTW, any copying of this new canvas needs to be done after the onload completes (eg. call copyToCanvas() inside onload to assure readiness.